# Call to undefined method query\builder::with()

Tags: php, laravel-5

The following code worked fine but now i need to select only particular set of records from the table based on the authenticated user. How can i achieve this? thank you.

Worked code

```
        $spares = \App\Spares::with('brand','model')->paginate(5);
```

New code that i need to get(need to select only the spares that are related to a particular retailer )

```
        $spares = DB::table('spares')->where('retailer_id', '=', $retailer_id)->with('brand','model')->paginate(5);
```

When i run the code it gets me the error as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `with()` with the Class `DB - QueryBuilder`, if you want to make it work then convert it into Models which should extends `Eloquent` class, this is how you can do this:

```
Spare::with('brand', 'model')
      ->where('retailer_id', $retailer_id)
      ->paginate(5);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much